# Keeping track of entire email thread with laravel-imap

Tags: php, laravel, imap

I'm using webklex's laravel-imap package and I'm doing a pretty standard pull on all the info, parsing, then storing info for each mail into the database.

It works functionally, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to keep track of entire mail threads related to a single originating message. So if Someone sends in a request that results in a thread of 7 more replies, I wanted to have 8 database entries for this (one for each resulting reply/message)

I've pulled in the header info to get the message ID but it doesn't seem to match like I expected and I think I'm just misunderstanding the usage here

How can I properly use the header info to keep track of each single response in a thread?

```
    $aMessages = $inboxFolder->messages()->all()->get();
    
    foreach($aMessages as $oMessage) {
        $uid = $oMessage->getUid();

        $body = $oMessage->getHTMLBody();
        $date_sent = $oMessage->getDate();
        $subject   = $oMessage->getSubject();
        $senderArray    = $oMessage->getFrom();
        $senderName = strval($senderArray[0]->personal);
        $senderEmail = $senderArray[0]->mail;
        $header = $oMessage->getHeaderInfo();

        $message_header_id = $header->message_id;

            $sql = "INSERT INTO MAIL
                    ( MESSAGE_UID, MESSAGE_SENDER, MESSAGE_SENDER_EMAIL, MESSAGE_SUBJECT,  MESSAGE_SENT_TIME, MESSAGE_CONTENT,MESSAGE_HEADER_ID, MESSAGE_PROCESSED )
                    VALUES ( ?, ?, ?,?, ?,?, ?, 'N' )";

            DB::connection('odbc')->statement($sql, [$uid, (string)$senderName, (string)$senderEmail, (string)$subject, (string)$date_sent, (string)$formatted_body, (string)$message_header_id]);
        }
```

Comment: Here's a good intro to how messages reference each other: https://cr.yp.to/immhf/thread.html there are two systems and you should probably support both: References and In-Reply-To.

Comment: @Max first of all: Thanks so much for that link! That's a helpful resource going forward. So if I understand right, in-reply-to should always reference the ID of the parent/origin message then?

Comment: Yes, parent message.  If References is there, the first in the list may be the origin message.